# Linux matlab tcp cannot connect

Tags: linux, matlab, networking, tcp, ip

I'm communicating with a robotic arm via matlab tcp(ethernet cable) at windows using java classes. It works well i send some integer values and receive. The problem is when i try to work on linux i cannot connect. I don't think that the problem is on code but i still share my code and matlab output. (i open matlab with sudo permission).

```
host         = '169.254.131.130';
port         = 10300;
int32 roll
roll         = 457;
int32 a;
int32 b;
int32 c;
int32 d;
%% Socket connection

    javaaddpath('tcpip');
    import java.net.Socket
    import java.io.*
    inputSocket = [];

while true
       try
            fprintf(1, 'Connecting to %s:%d\n', host, port);
            % throws if unable to connect
            inputSocket = Socket(host, port);
            fprintf(1, 'Connected to server\n');
            break;
        catch
            if ~isempty(inputSocket)
                inputSocket.close;
            end
            pause(1);
        end
end

 %% read data from the socket
input_stream   = inputSocket.getInputStream;
d_input_stream = DataInputStream(input_stream);
bytes_available = input_stream.available;
tic
for i = (1:100)

 output_stream = inputSocket.getOutputStream; 
 d_output_stream = DataOutputStream(output_stream);
 d_output_stream.writeInt(i); 
 d_output_stream.flush;
 %pause(0.01);

while (bytes_available == 0)
    bytes_available = input_stream.available;
end

fprintf(1, 'Reading %d bytes\n',bytes_available);
data_reader = DataReader(d_input_stream);
message = int32(data_reader.readBuffer(4));
if message(4) < 0
    message(4) = message(4) + 256;
end
result = message(1) * 2^24 + message(2) * 2^16 + message(3) * 2^8 + message(4)
bytes_available = 0;
end
toc
```

MATLAB output is

```
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
Connecting to 169.254.131.130:10300
```

again again and again

Comment: can you ping the ip address of the robotic arm? If not, the problem is with your ip settings, not your code

Comment: The output is ---- From 192.168.2.4 icmp_seq=9 Destination Host Unreachable ----- ------ 169.254.131.130 ping statistics ---
13 packets transmitted, 0 received, +12 errors, 100% packet loss, time 12055ms
pipe 3
-----any suggestion? How do i fix my ip settings ?

Comment: It depends on your linux distro, but its not hard to figure out how to set ip settings through some internet searching. What settings to use depends on how you set it up on the windows machine. Did you use a static IP? Does the ARM have a static ip address by default, or does it use DHCP? You can find out what your current IP settings are by typing `ifconfig.` if you have a manual for the robotic arm that should have some info

Comment: My distro is mint which is ubuntu based. The point is that i didint change anything. In arm i just write data to buffer and flush it. No extra connection settings. In matlab part i just connect it via java class codes it is not low level that. In windows i didint change anything everything is auto. If u suggest that i should compare windows and linux's connection settings i do and everything is auto.

Comment: Probably Windows automatically handled the ip settings for you, but linux will either not handle it automatically, or is handling it automatically, but differently. Your matlab code is fine, this is a network connectivity question. Either the robot arm is serving as a DHCP server, or windows is negotiating automatically. You may need to specify a manual ip address in linux to get it to work